# Can not deserialize a javascript array of object into C# array

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm bulding an array of object in javascript as follows :

```
var tabDiscount = []
for(var i=0; i<someArray.length; i++){
  var refdiscountpair = { productCode: $("#Ref" + i).html(), discount: discountValue }
  tabDiscount.push(refdiscountpair);
}
```

which seems to work fine. I then store this array in an hiddefield

```
$HFDiscount.val(JSON.stringify(tabDiscount));
```

so when the form is posted I get the hiddenfield value server-side. I have a C# class RefDiscountPair :

```
 [Serializable]
    public class RefDiscountPair
    {
        public string productCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int discount
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public RefDiscountPair()
        {
        }
    }
```

and I try to deserialize the array of javascript object into an array of RefDiscountPair. I've tried using the JSON .NET package (Newtonsoft.Json) :

```
RefDiscountPair[] test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RefDiscountPair[]>(HFDiscount.Value);
```

whcih raises a `JsonSerializationException`.

I've also tried to use the JavaScriptSerializer class :

```
string[] test = js.Deserialize<string[]>(js.Deserialize<string>(HFDiscount.Value));
foreach (string s in test)
{
   RefDiscountPair p = js.Deserialize<RefDiscountPair>(s);
}
```

**Exception**

> `MissingMethodException` (no parameterless constructor defined for type of 'system.string'. javascriptserializer).

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

This is the structure of the JSON I recieve :

```
"\"[{\\\"productCode\\\": \\\"1111111\\\", \\\"discount\\\": \\\"5\\\"}, {\\\"productCode\\\": \\\"2222222\\\", \\\"discount\\\": \\\"5\\\"}]\""
```

which result in the following error message :

```
Error converting value "[{"productCode": "1111111", "discount": "5"}, {"productCode": "2222222", "discount": "5"}]"
```

Comment: It might be better to wrap your array inside a wrapper object so you get JSON which looks like

{ items: yourArray }

Comment: Have you tried deserializing a single object instead of an array? Try to limit the amount of things that could go wrong.

Comment: @A.Rama deserialazing just one object into a RefDiscountPair object with the JSON.NET package seems to work fine. I don't get why I can't deserialize the whole array into a RefDiscountPair array in C# though.

Comment: Why there is a `string` at the end of your json?

Comment: @aloisdg I was wondering the same at the moment, Im goign to check the value of the JSON step by step

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to check if your JSON is correct. `HFDiscount.Value` property should contain something like that (structure, not values):

```
[  
   {  
      "productCode":"535854302-3",
      "discount":11
   },
   {  
      "productCode":"905491934-5",
      "discount":6
   }
]
```

For deserialization I suggest you to use JSON.Net (what was your first attempt). You don't need to have `Serialization` attribute and default constructor for your model:

```
public class RefDiscountPair
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can easily deserialize JSON:

```
var refDiscountPairs = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<RefDiscountPair>>(HFDiscount.Value);
```

**EDIT:** You have some problems with your JSON. I created a simple demo and it worked fine. Model I used:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public string HFDiscount { get; set; }
}
```

Cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HFDiscount)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Javascript:

```
var tabDiscount = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var refdiscountpair = { productCode: "code" + i, discount: i }
    tabDiscount.push(refdiscountpair);
}
$("#HFDiscount").val(JSON.stringify(tabDiscount));
```

And controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(IndexModel model)
 {
     var refDiscountPairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<RefDiscountPair>>(model.HFDiscount);
     return View();
 }
```

**EDIT:** It turns out that you are actually using pure ASP.NET. I tried it too and it works well.

ASPX:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HFDiscount" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_OnClick" />
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var refDiscountPairs =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<RefDiscountPair>>(HFDiscount.Value);
}
```

You need to verify all steps and find the place where JSON gets corrupted. Start from inspecting hidden field value in browser.

Comment: I edited my question to show what kind of JSON I recieve, maybe this will help cause I get the same exception as before.

Comment: I added more examples in the answer.

Comment: only ASP.NET. No MVC involved

Comment: I added info for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple deserialize, only try to convert it to list of object:

```
js.Deserialize<List<RefDiscountPair>>(HFDiscount.Value));
```

But make sure that JSON string in hiddenfield is right one. If you get any exception in this case, then should try to fix the JSON string in javascript, or remove some additional character in your code before desrialize it

**EDIT:**

Definitely your JSON string is not correct, you have to change it. You can do in JS code or in C#. If you want to fix it in code behind you can use below code:

```
var jsonStr = "\"[{\\\"productCode\\\": \\\"1111111\\\", \\\"discount\\\": \\\"5\\\"}, {\\\"productCode\\\": \\\"2222222\\\", \\\"discount\\\": \\\"5\\\"}]\"";
if (jsonStr.StartsWith("\""))
    jsonStr = jsonStr.Substring(1);
if(jsonStr.EndsWith("\""))
    jsonStr = jsonStr.Substring(0 , jsonStr.Length-1);    

jsonStr = jsonStr.Replace("\\", "");

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

serializer.Deserialize<List<RefDiscountPair>>(jsonStr);
```

I tested this and it's working fine

Comment: I get an exception Unable to cast an object of type string into an object of type List. Wha do you mean by fixing the JSON ? The Hiddefield value does represent a JSON String of an Array of object and seems to be correct. What more can I do than JSON.stringify(array) ?

Comment: can you post the JSON string as well?

Comment: I modified my code, that should working for your case

Answer (score 0):

```
   string jsonInput = "Your json STRING";

                    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer resp = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonInput);
                    foreach (JObject str in resp)
                    {
                        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

                        YourObject p = (YourObject)serializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(str), typeof(YourObject));
                        YourObjectAsListOfObject.Add(p);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your json.

Here is a working example : [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1CeKzN).

Code :

```
// you can generate your class with http://json2csharp.com/
public class RefDiscountPair
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
}

public void Main()
{
    string json = "[{\"productCode\": \"1111111\", \"discount\": \"5\"}, {\"productCode\": \"2222222\", \"discount\": \"5\"}]";

    var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RefDiscountPair>>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(m[0].Discount);
}
```